# How to wrap long titles in lattice graphics in R?

Tags: r, graphics, lattice, word-wrap

I need to add a long title to a graphic created with the `likert` function from the `HH` package, that uses lattice, but it (lattice) doesn't have this facility. Is there a way to do this?

**My code**:

```
library(HH)
ppi <- 150
jpeg("ssb_%02d.jpg", width=7*ppi, height=4*ppi, res=ppi)

for(i in 1:2){
    plot_obj <- likert(Grup ~ . | Grup, data = ssb, as.percent = TRUE, positive.order = TRUE,
        main=list(label = items[i,], cex=1.2), xlab=list(label="Percent", cex=1.1),
        ylab="", ylab.right = list("Subjects per group", cex=1.1),
        scales = list(y = list(relation = "free", labels=""), cex=1.1),
        layout = c(1, 2), auto.key=list(space="bottom", columns=3, title="", cex=1.1)) 

    print(plot_obj)
}

dev.off()
```

**My data**:

```
ssb <- structure(list(`Strongly Disagree` = c(2L, 1L), `Moderate Disagree` = 1:2, 
    `Slightly Disagree` = c(3L, 1L), `Slightly Agree` = c(1L, 
    5L), `Moderate Agree` = 4:5, `Strongly Agree` = c(9L, 6L), 
    Grup = c("Experimental grup", "Control grup")), .Names = c("Strongly Disagree", 
"Moderate Disagree", "Slightly Disagree", "Slightly Agree", "Moderate Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Grup"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Title items**:

```
items <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1. În cele mai multe privinţe, viaţa mea corespunde idealului meu.", 
"2. Până în prezent am primit cele mai importante lucruri pe care le doresc în viață."
), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

**UPDATE**

Graphic titles are not added directly, but dynamically, from a data frame, and the data frame are loaded from a .csv file. If, as was suggested in comments, I add a `\n` to the long title in the .csv file this doesn't work.

Comment: I think that should just be `\n`. For example, `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod\ntempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."`

Comment: The code snippet in my answer works for me (the lines are broken at `\n`.

Comment: I'd use `strwrap()` to automate the text-wrapping. If your long title is stored in a string called `mainText`, just do something like `mainFormatted <- paste(strwrap(mainText, width=45), collapse="\n")` to get a wrapped version that's about 45 characters wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem, thanks to @josh-obrien. Now, when the graphic title is longer than 70 characters it is wrapped to 65 characters wide version.

```
library(HH)
ppi <- 150
jpeg("ssb_%02d.jpg", width=7*ppi, height=4*ppi, res=ppi)

for(i in 1:2){

    if(stri_length(items[i,])>70){
        graphic.title <- paste(strwrap(items[i,], width = 65), collapse="\n")
    } else {
        graphic.title <- items[i,]
    }

    plot_obj <- likert(Grup ~ . | Grup, data = ssb, as.percent = TRUE, positive.order = TRUE,
    main=list(label = graphic.title, cex=1.2), xlab=list(label="Percent", cex=1.1),
    ylab="", ylab.right = list("Subjects per group", cex=1.1),
    scales = list(y = list(relation = "free", labels=""), cex=1.1),
    layout = c(1, 2), auto.key=list(space="bottom", columns=3, title="", cex=1.1))

    print(plot_obj)
}

dev.off()
```