# R: How to wrap character columns to print to 2 lines in ggplot, but they're NOT titles?

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-wrap, ggalluvial

There are myriad similar questions for splitting character strings to 2 lines with `\n` and `cat` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010621/r-insert-newline-in-a-variable-not-for-printing-purposes?rq=3)), `paste` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112786/how-to-split-the-main-title-of-a-plot-in-2-or-more-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1)), `strwrap` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650924/how-to-wrap-long-titles-in-lattice-graphics-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and `writeLines` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317830/r-do-i-need-to-add-explicit-new-line-character-with-print)). But all of these either anticipate the output being explicitly printed immediately thereafter, or printing will happen automatically by `plot`/`ggplot`; in the latter case, examples typically relate to  (axis) titles.

I've created an [alluvial plot](https://github.com/corybrunson/ggalluvial) which creates the following plot:

[image: Alluvial]

From the following post-processed table of data:

[image: table]

I'm trying to force certain cells in "FnGpRealm" and "Effect Type" columns to wrap to two lines. An example of the various similar approached I've tried (relevant code chunk only):

```
dplyr::mutate(FnGpRealm = stringr::str_replace_all(string = FnGpRealm,
                                                            pattern = "Ma: Inshore/Shelf",
                                                            replacement = paste0("Ma:", "\n", "Inshore/Shelf"))
```

I've also tried "Ma:\nInshore/Shelf" as the replacement, used "/n" as the `collapse` in a `paste`, wrapped `writeLines` around the whole `str_replace_all` block... all to no avail. If I try to `print` / `writeLines` the column onto itself after adding the `/n`, it kills the column completely:

```
tmp$FnGpRealm
```

> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010621/r-insert-newline-in-a-variable-not-for-printing-purposes?rq=3) "Ma:\nInshore/Shelf"

```
tmp$FnGpRealm <- writeLines(tmp$FnGpRealm)

tmp$FnGpRealm
```

> NULL. Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: `FnGpRealm`.

Based on the extent to which I understand how `\n` works in all of this, it seems character strings with regex special characters like `\n` get autochecked by some functions (`cat`, `paste`, `writeLines`), probably also within (gg)plot calls, which then wrap them to multiple lines when detected. But since `ggalluvial` populates its elements using character cells which evidently aren't autochecked the same way... is there a way to wrap those strings within the column natively? So when `ggalluvial` prints them, they're already wrapped? Or is this not a thing?

My fallback is just to rename stuff shorter like I already did with macro/mesopredator to Ma/Me. But that kinda sucks.

Thanks in advance!

edit: `dput(head(df))` output:

> structure(list(`Effect Type` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  3L),
> levels = c("Top-down: Direct Predation", "Top-down: Risk Effects",
> "Top-down: Trophic Cascade", "Competition", "BU:NVS:SAF", "BU:NVS:EAE"
> ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), `Effect Size` = structure(c(1L,
> 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("3", "2", "1"), class = c("ordered",
> "factor")), Count = c(16L, 8L, 32L, 11L, 2L, 17L)), class =
> c("grouped_df",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
> -6L), groups = structure(list(
> `Effect Type` = structure(1:3, levels = c("Top-down: Direct Predation",
> "Top-down: Risk Effects", "Top-down: Trophic Cascade", "Competition",
> "BU:NVS:SAF", "BU:NVS:EAE"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
> )), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:5, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",
> "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Cheers Rui, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `stringr::str_wrap` directly inside `aes` when specifying the `label` aesthetic should be fine:

```r
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(data = data,
       aes(axis1 = FnGpRealm, axis2 = EffectType, y = Count)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = factor(EffectSize)), alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_stratum(fill = 'white') +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = stringr::str_wrap(after_stat(stratum), 12))) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
  scale_fill_manual('Effect\nSize',
                    values = c('3' = '#55b69a', '2' = '#9894c6', 
                               '1' = '#e38642')) +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8))
```

[image]

---

**Data OCR'd from table in OP**

```r
data <- structure(list(FnGpRealm = c("Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Ma: Inshore/Shelf", "Ma: Pelagic", "Ma: Pelagic", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", "Me: Inshore/Shelf", 
"Me: Pelagic", "Me: Pelagic", "Me: Pelagic", "Me: Pelagic"), 
    EffectType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Top-down: Direct Predation", 
    "Top-down: Risk Effects", "Top-down: Trophic Cascade", "Competition", 
    "BU:NVS:SAF", "BU:NVS:EAE"), class = "factor"), EffectSize = c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L), Count = c(16L, 8L, 32L, 11L, 2L, 17L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you refer to "/n" - is this a typo? The newline character is "\n" (back slash, not forward slash) - is this what's causing the issue?

Also, I tried but wasn't able to reproduce this problem on my system:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggalluvial)

penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(species = if_else(species == "Adelie", "Some other\nlong name\nfor 'Adelie'", species)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(species, island, year),
              names_from = sex,
              values_from = body_mass_g,
              values_fn = sum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(axis1 = species,
             axis2 = island,
             y = female)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = factor(year))) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Jared. I was using \n in my code yes - easy to accidentally use forwardslash when typing just because I use backslash so infrequently! Weird this just works for you and not for me.... are you on windows OS maybe? Trying to think what else could cause the same thing to work for you not me...!?

Comment: Sorry @dez93_2000, I have no idea what the root cause of the problem is. I use macOS so maybe that's a factor? Regardless, Allen Cameron's answer is an excellent solution so I'd suggest using that (+1)